# why can't log keycode value to the console window?

Tags: javascript

Hey guy's I'm trying to make a snake game in JS. Right now I'm making the function that will determine the direction of the snake, but at the moment I just want to log the keycode of any given key to the console, but it comes up as undefined? Why is this? I have the keycode stored into a variable before I log it? thanks for the help:)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//set canvas dimension equal to css dimension
canvas.width = 750;
canvas.height = 500;

//create stroke
ctx.strokeStyle = 'limegreen';
ctx.strokeRect(375, 250, 15, 15);

//create square
ctx.fillStyle = 'limegreen';
ctx.fillRect(375, 250, 15, 15);

//read user's direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', changeDirection);

function changeDirection(e) {
 let code = e.keycode;
 console.log(code);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snake Game</title>
 <style>
  body {
   background-color: #333;
  }

  canvas {
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   margin: auto;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 750px;
   height: 500px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe use keyCode and not keycode? Logging the whole `e` would help to show this

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try e.keyCode instead of e.keycode

Comment: dang it I had a feeling it was a typo, sorry.

Comment: you can use "debugger;" statement to find issues like this. :)